# Multiple JS models with multiple materials

Tags: three.js, webgl, game-engine

I need to load multiple models for map in my game...
But when i'm loading all of them, my fps is going down=( But models are no huge, just only 3k poly for 1 model.

```
function buildHouse(Bnum, x, y, z, Yangle, scale)
{
    var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader( true );
    jsonLoader.load( "js/map/obj/Building"+Bnum+".js", addModelToScene1, 'model_source/textures' );

    function addModelToScene1( geometry, materials)
    {
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry,new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
        mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = scale;
        mesh.castShadow = true;
        mesh.rotation.y = Yangle;
        mesh.position.x = x;
        mesh.position.y = y;
        mesh.position.z = z;
        BuildingsObject.add( mesh );
    };
}
function createBuildings()
{
    buildHouse(1,600,0,100,-Math.PI/2,10);
    buildHouse(2,250,0,100,-Math.PI,10);
    buildHouse(3,0,17,0,-Math.PI,20);
    scene.add(BuildingsObject);
}
createBuildings();
```

In this exaple i'm loading only 3 models, but when the count of models growing till 10 - fps is about 15=(

I tried to load the model without materials as a result - do not drop the FPS

Сan anyone give some advice on how to optimize this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in loading models multiple times... I've created scene and exported it into one js file, fps is in normal range, its strange.. but works